# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta para guardar una fecha en milisegundos en Firestore con Node.js, en formato local (ej: GMT-0400) o UTC?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, date, timestamp

Estoy trabajando con un cliente Nuxt.js y un servidor Node.js con Firebase. Y quiero crear (o actualizar) la fecha de nacimiento de un usuario en la base de datos de Firebase Cloud Firestore, para ello, desde el cliente paso la fecha en formato de milisegundos al servidor (para que se cree o actualice la fecha de naciemiento) de este modo:

**Cliente:** Crear un objeto tipo Date a partir de un string, pasar a UTC y obtener su tiempo en milisegundos para pasar al servidor. (A tener en cuenta, el objeto `{fechaNacimiento: fechaNacimientoMiliSegundos}`  es el que se pasa para que se actualice la fecha de nacimiento con axios)

Pasos para el cliente:

```
let fechaNacimientoString = '2020-09-09T20:47:07.000Z';
let fechaNacimiento = new Date( fechaNacimientoString );
fechaNacimiento.setMinutes( fechaNacimiento.getMinutes() + fechaNacimiento.getTimezoneOffset() );
// fechaNacimientoMiliSegundos es la variable que paso 
// para crear (o actualizar) la fecha de nacimiento del usuario.
let fechaNacimientoMiliSegundos = fechaNacimiento.getTime();
```

**Servidor:** Utiliza express.js y recibe desde el req.body.fechaNacimiento (en milisegundos) y actualiza.

Ejemplo de actualización:

```
const { uidUsuario } = req.params;
const { fechaNacimiento } = req.body;

const fechaNacimientoTimestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis ( fechaNacimiento );

await admin.firestore().collection(COLECCION_USUARIO).doc(uidUsuario).update({
    fechaNacimiento: fechaNacimientoTimestamp 
});
```

Pero, mi duda es la siguiente, como se ve en el cliente, primero transformo la fecha (fechaNacimiento) a UTC para obtener su formato en milisegundos para poder pasar al servidor.
¿Hay que hacer este proceso siempre

```
fechaNacimiento.setMinutes( fechaNacimiento.getMinutes() + fechaNacimiento.getTimezoneOffset() );
```

para enviar la fecha en milisegundos y poder operar con la base de datos? O sea, ¿sería la forma correcta?

Es que si hago de esta forma, veo que respeta la zona horaria (acá en Paraguay GMT-0400) y también respeta el UTC. (*Ejemplo de la fecha que estoy utilizando: 2020-09-09T20:47:07.000Z*)

**Formato local (GMT-0400):** Wed Sep 09 2020 20:47:07 GMT-0400

**UTC:** Thu, 10 Sep 2020 00:47:07 GMT

Ejemplo de diferencia de hora: https://24timezones.com/es/difference/asuncion/utc

Perooo, si no hago de esta forma, no respeta las horas, ya que el formato local debería ser el que puse con el formato de mi zona local (o sea, Wed Sep 09 2020 20:47:07 GMT-0400) pero sale otra cosa:

**Formato local (GMT-0400):** Wed Sep 09 2020 16:47:07 GMT-0400

**UTC:** Wed, 09 Sep 2020 20:47:07 GMT

Comment: Hola, la fecha UTC es universal. Cuando la creas aqui -> `let fechaNacimientoString = '2020-09-09T20:47:07.000Z'` esa fecha está en UTC, lo puedes notar por la Z al final del string. No hace falta hacerle nada. Despues, para visualizar esa fecha en tu zona horaria solo debes restar o sumar tu timezone (como mencionas -4 horas en paraguay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introducción

Para responder tu pregunta primero hay que entender algunos conceptos.

- ### UTC

[UTC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado) significa **Tiempo universal coordinado**

> Un intermedio entre la versión en inglés Coordinated Universal Time CUT y la versión en francés Temps universel coordonné TUC

Es el principal estándar de tiempo por el cual el mundo regula los relojes y el tiempo. Para la mayoría de los propósitos comunes, UTC es sinónimo de GMT.

---

- ### Zona Horaria/Huso Horario

[Huso horario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huso_horario) es cada una de las partes en que queda dividida la superficie terrestre por 24 meridianos igualmente espaciados y en que suele regir convencionalmente un mismo horario.

Todos los *husos horarios* se definen en relación con el denominado Tiempo Universal Coordinado ([UTC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado)), que es un *huso horario* centrado sobre el meridiano de Greenwich (también conocido como meridiano cero):

[image: Husos horarios estándares establecidos el 31 de mayo de 1999. Actualizado: 27 de diciembre de 2020]

Las zonas horarias de todo el mundo se expresan como desviaciones positivas o negativas de [UTC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado), tomando como referencia el meridiano cero o meridiano de Greenwich.

---

- ### EPOCH

Es una fecha y hora a partir de las cuales una computadora mide la hora del sistema.

Unix Epoch (también llamada tiempo Unix) es el número de segundos desde el **1 de enero de 1970 a las 00:00:00 UTC**.

En Javascript, `Date.now()` y `new Date().getTime()` devuelven los milisegundos desde el Epoch UTC.

---

### Problema

En tu pregunta mencionas lo siguiente:

> Es que si hago de esta forma, veo que respeta la zona horaria (acá en Paraguay GMT-0400) y también respeta el UTC. (Ejemplo de la fecha que estoy utilizando: 2020-09-09T20:47:07.000Z)
> Formato local (GMT-0400): Wed Sep 09 2020 20:47:07 GMT-0400
> UTC: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 00:47:07 GMT

El ejemplo que das `(Ejemplo de la fecha que estoy utilizando: 2020-09-09T20:47:07.000Z)` no está bien interpretado:

La fecha `2020-09-09T20:47:07.000Z` está en UTC, es decir para saber qué fecha/hora es en tu zona horaria, debes restar o sumar tu huso horario. Como mencionas, en Paraguay son 4 horas menos (-04:00), por lo tanto la fecha `2020-09-09T20:47:07.000Z` UTC en Paraguay es: `2020-09-09T16:47:07.000-0400`.

En resumen, si en UTC (El meridiano de Greenwich) son las `20hs` en Paraguay son las `16hs` (4 horas menos que en UTC).

Pero en Argentina por ejemplo, son 3 horas menos, por lo tanto:
Si son las `20hs` UTC, en distintos paises dependiendo de su zona horaria serán horarios distintos:

- Paraguay 16hs (-04:00)
- Argentina 17hs (-03:00)
- Vancouver 12hs (-08:00)
- UTC 20hs (- 0 horas)

### Solución

Para guardar fechas en una base de datos puedes simplemente guardar los milisegundos desde el epoch ya que, como se mencionó anteriormente, es una hora universal (UTC).

Para guardar los milisegundos desde el epoch simplemente usa el método [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) del objeto `Date`

```js
let fecha = new Date();
console.log("Fecha en tu tiempo local: ",fecha.toLocaleString());
console.log("Milisegundos desde el unix epoch: ", fecha.getTime());

// La guardamos en una "base de datos" (Un objeto en memoria)
let baseDeDatos = {
  fechaGuardada: fecha
};

// Luego la recuperamos para su uso
let fechaGuardadaMilis = baseDeDatos.fechaGuardada;
let fechaObjeto = new Date(fechaGuardadaMilis);

console.log("Fecha recuperada en tu tiempo local: ",fechaObjeto.toLocaleString());
console.log("Milisegundos recuperados desde el unix epoch: ", fechaObjeto.getTime());
```

---

### EDIT

Un ejemplo al crear una fecha desde un ISO string con y sin la Z:

```js
let fechaConZ = new Date("2020-09-09T20:47:07Z");
console.log("Con la Z de UTC: ", fechaConZ);
let fechaSinZ = new Date("2020-09-09T20:47:07");
console.log("Sin la Z: ", fechaSinZ);
let fechaConUnTimezone = new Date("2020-09-09T20:47:07-0400");
console.log("Con la timezone de Paraguay: ", fechaConUnTimezone);
```

NOTA: Cuando haces `console.log` te muestra la fecha en formato ISO y en UTC.

Comment: Graaciass amigo! Solo para aclarar, ¿entonces al colocar Z en el string fecha se esta representando como UTC ( ejemplo: ```2020-09-09T20:47:07.000Z``` ) pero si no coloco la Z ( o sea ```2020-09-09T20:47:07``` o como mostraste en tu explicación ```2020-09-09T16:47:07.000-0400``` ) se representa de forma local?

Comment: Exacto, si haces un `new Date("2020-09-09T20:47:07")`  (Sin la Z) Js va a tomar la hora local de tu computadora. O Puedes agregarle el timezone. Lo agregaré como ejemplo en la respuesta

Comment: @guillepaivag si la respuesta te ayudó, considera marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!