# Datepicker se desfasa con 15 horas

Tags: datepicker, horas

trabajo en un proyecto de laravel con vue y tengo un Datepicker que llama una lista de acuerdo a la fecha seleccionada, me encuentro en Colombia, todo va bien entre las 9am y las 7pm, cuando no se esta dentro de ese rango el datapiker trae las listas de ayer, no encuentro como corregirlo.

```
        <datepicker :language="langEs" name="start-date" v-model="moreParams.fecha" v-validate="'required'">
        </datepicker>
    
    <vuetable ref="vuetable" api-url="{{ route("api.citas.medico.getCitasHoy", ['id' => $medico->id]) }}"
                        :fields="fields" :css="css.table" :show-sort-icons="true" :sort-order="sortOrder"
                        :per-page="perPage" pagination-path="meta" :append-params="moreParams" :row-class="onRowClass"
                        @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData" @vuetable:row-clicked="onRowClick">
                        <div slot="id" slot-scope="props">
                            @{{ props.rowData.paciente.identificacion }}
                        </div>
                        <div slot="paciente" slot-scope="props">
                            @{{ props.rowData.paciente.primer_nombre }} @{{ props.rowData.paciente.primer_apellido }}
                        </div>
                        <template slot="asigna" slot-scope="props">
                            @{{ props.rowData.asistente.name }} @{{ props.rowData.asistente.last_name }}
                        </template>
                        <template slot="eps" slot-scope="props">
                            @{{ props.rowData.eps.nombre_comercial }}
                        </template>
                        <template slot="preferencial" slot-scope="props">
                            @{{ props.rowData.preferencia }}
                        </template>
    
                        <template slot="tipo_servicio" slot-scope="props">
                            @{{ props.rowData.servicio[0].descripcion }}
                        </template>
                        <div slot="actions" slot-scope="props">
                            <b-button-group>
                                <b-button variant="outline-danger" v-b-tooltip.top title="Cancelacion de cita"
                                    @click.stop="openModalCancelarCita(props.rowData)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
                                </b-button>
                                <b-button variant="outline-primary" :disabled="props.rowData.prioridad !== false"
                                    v-b-tooltip.top title="Marcar como prioridad"
                                    @click.stop="asignarPrioridad(props.rowData)">
                                    <i class="fas fa-award fa-2x"></i>
                                </b-button>
                                <b-button variant="outline-primary" @click.stop="openFormCita(props.rowData)" v-b-tooltip.top
                                    title="Actualizar">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user-edit fa-2x"></i>
                                </b-button>
                            </b-button-group>
                        </div>
                    </vuetable>
        
        moreParams: {
           fecha: new Date(),                    
        }
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve el controlador

```
$perPage = $request->has('per_page') ? (int) $request->per_page : null;
        return CitaResource::collection($this->citaRepository->pushCriteria(new FieldIsValue('medico_id', $request->medico_id))->pushCriteria(new FieldIsValue('cancelada', false))->scopeQuery(function ($scope) use ($request) {
            $fecha_inicio = Carbon::parse($request->fecha)->format('Y-m-d');
            return $scope->whereDate('fecha_inicio', '=', $fecha_inicio)->where('espera', '=', false);
        })->pushCriteria(new WithRelations(['paciente', 'asistente', 'eps', 'servicios']))->orderBy('hora', 'asc')->paginate($perPage));
```

Las horas de mysql son correctas, los datos se guardan bien durante el periodo mencionado, creo que es el datepicker porque manejo otras fechas en otras vistas y va bien.

Al subir al proyecto a Amazon pasa igual.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: En dónde traes las listas? Agrega el código de cómo estas haciendo la búsqueda. Lo más seguro es que sea un problema de zona horaria (Timezone). Hace un tiempo contesté una pregunta relacionada a la zona horaria. Quizas te aclare un poco mientras tanto. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/483538/86914

Comment: Por favor agregalo a la pregunta. Debes hacer click en [edit]

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue.